# C# UWP Save localsettings in another folder

Tags: c#, uwp, settings

I have a problem, I want to store some Appdata with the localsettings function. But I dont want to save them in the default settingfile but rather in the LocalState Folder.

Is there any way?

Thats how I save them:

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["Test"] = "Data";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> C# UWP Save localsettings in another folder

The the folder path of  LocalSettings api was created internal, we can't specific other folder for `LocalSettings`, if you do want to save localsettings in another folder, we suggest you store the setting manually with Windows Storage api.

For example

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder =
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
Windows.Storage.StorageFile sampleFile =
    await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("sample.txt",
        Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting); 
await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, "setting parameter");
```

For more please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files)